# Looking for a shortcut to iterate through generator

Tags: python, generator

When I want to access the elements in a generator, I have to do first:

```
items = [item for item in item_generator]
```

Then get what I want in `items`

However simple as it is, typing it is somewhat tedious when such operation is quite frequent.

So is there a *shortcut* or *existing built-in function* that do unpack the generator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about converting the generator to a list?

```
item = list(item_generator)[2]
```

Comment: @xiaohan2012: Accept the answer maybe? :-)

Comment: I forgot it, sorry. Excited to get back to code at that time. :)